# Firebase Ios Swift Authentication Problem

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, firebase-authentication

My code doesn't work properly. I created google firebase Authentication. My code is down

```
    @IBAction func loginClicked(_ sender: UlButton) {
      if let email = usernameText.text, let password = passwordText.text { 
         Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) {authResult, error in 
            self.makeAlert(titleInput: "Error", messagelnput:"Error")
    }
    self.performSegue(withldentifier: "goToViewController", sender: nil) 
    }
}
```

Then I wrote this code. Error message is displayed when you enter wrong email and wrong password on login page. But it also goes to the other page(Home Page, ldentifier: "goToViewController"). I dont want do this. When I enter the wrong email and wrong password, I want to show error message only.

How can I do that?
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `performSegue` inside the closure response of firebase

```
 @IBAction func loginClicked(_ sender: UlButton) {
      if let email = usernameText.text, let password = passwordText.text { 
         Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) {authResult, error in 
           if error == nil { 
              self.performSegue(withldentifier: "goToViewController", sender: nil) 
           }
           else { 
              self.makeAlert(titleInput: "Error", messagelnput:"Error") 
            } 
        }
    }
}
```